# Script to show text if cell value is below zero, otherwise show the calculation

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am completely new to scripts and don't know where to begin, so I hope I can get a bit of help here for this one time task that I have.

My problem is as follows:

If cells in my calculations in column G show values below zero, I would like to write a text message "No help required". But if the value is above zero, the cell should show the value of the calculation.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

paste this formula in row 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G1:G<0; "No help required"; G1:G))
```

---

### UPDATE:

paste in G9:

```
=IF(F9-(I9+K9+M9+O9+Q9+S9)<0; "No help required"; F9-(I9+K9+M9+O9+Q9+S9))
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not explaining myself properly. In my cell in e.g. G9 there is a calculation already =F9-(I9+K9+M9+O9+Q9+S9) - and depending on the result, I would either like the sum to be shown if it is above 0, or if it is below 0 I would like a text displayed "no help required". Hope that makes it clearer.